# Unable to open password-protected raster in Georeferencer

Tags: raster, gdal, qgis-3, pdf, password

I am using QGIS 3.4. I am unable to open a PDF file, a password-protected topo sheet in the Georeferencer. I do have the password.

The error message is:

> A password is needed. You can specify it through PDF_USER_PWD configuration option/ USER_PWD open option.

Where can I find this option?

Comment: Thanks to GIS stack Exchange. I got two wonderful solutions, of which one perfectly solved my problem. At the same I am surprised to note that my question has been closed as " Off - Topic" by your authorized team. I disagree with that decision because i) Question is directly related to first step in GIS, ie georeferencing ii) This or similar questions are not available in your Q&A repository iii)Soulution was sought for a specific and practical issue of opening a Raster file in OGC complient Qgis 3.4. It hurts to be tagged as "off-topic'. No need to re-open it. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting *USER_PWD* or *GDAL_USER_PWD* as custom environment variable directly in QGIS (Settings -> Options -> System):

[image]

Keep an eye on all the other possible environment settings (i.e. *GDAL_PDF_DPI*, *GDAL_PDF_LAYERS* , *GDAL_PDF_LAYERS_OFF*): https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html

Comment: Thank you Friend Christoph. The solution suggested by you, that setting environment as GDAL_USER_PWD, and value a ' concerned password' did not work. After restarting Qdis GDAL, the same error that I posted in my question pops up. Thanks to you again for your effort in solving my problem dear friend.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings... Options... System section and set `PDF_USER_PWD` as a custom enviroment variable, here I've done that for a password of literally "password" in a test file:

[image]

restart QGIS, and this works for my test file, and I can load it into the georeferencer.

Fiddly if you have a load of PDFs with different passwords, in which case you might want to find an operating-system level way of de-passwording in bulk.

Comment: Thank you Friend Spacedman, The solution suggested by you has solved my problem. Any Password protected pdf Topo sheet files is opening, provided I give the 'value field in the setting' with that password. However, an error message pops up before closing for restarting "RunTimeError: Wrapped c/ c++ objec of type  TilesXYX/AlgorithmDirectory has been deleted" . Thanks to you again and to GIS Stack Exchange.